# PyPDF2 Help Printing Array Of Pages

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to search a PDF for a string, then print the pages containing that string to a new document.

The search as working, and it does make a new document, yet there are no pages contained in the new PDF. I would greatly appreciate any assistance, I am a beginner and I'm sure it's something simple I am missing. Thank you.

```
import fitz
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter


def findCopyDoc():
    filename = input("Enter file name: ")
    search_term = input("Enter search term: ")

    # Open file specified by user
    pdf_document = fitz.open(filename)

    for current_page in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.loadPage(current_page)
        
        if page.searchFor(search_term):
            # page_list == array to print to new file
            page_list = [current_page]
            print(f"{search_term} is located at {current_page + 1}.") # Add 1 to ignore index and show page number

            # Write to a new pdf
            file_base_name = filename.replace('.pdf', '')

            for i in page_list:
                pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
                with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
                    pdfWriter.write(f)
                    print("Writing...")
                    print("Complete...")
                    f.close()
                

findCopyDoc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining PyPDF2 and fitz. Those are not meant to be combined. Their objects/internal formats are completely different. Use one or the other.